# Using v4l2loopback in a docker container to create a camera

Tags: linux, docker, v4l2loopback

I want to create a fake webcam in a docker container, so I install v4l2loopback-dkms on a docker container with the "adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubuntu-jre" image.
When I run:
`sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1`

I get this error:
`mobprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.49-linuxkit`

I tried making v4l2loopback from the github repository using *make*, but I still get the same error.

Comment: For a couple of reasons, you can't install kernel modules from inside a container.  Containers also don't have any notion of hardware, though.  Would it make more sense to run this task in a full virtual machine, with a dedicated kernel and simulated hardware?

Comment: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702856/use-v4l2loopback-in-docker-dev-video0-missing-in-docker) someone got it to work, not saying what is the image, however. Hopefully that helps with what has to be installed